# Why flash is not used when I raise the power to 1.3+

Tags: flash, nikon-d90

I apologize my ignorance on the subject, I am a newbie and hence, ran into this problem.

My set up:

- Nikon D90
- Nikon SB700 flash
- PocketWizard MiniTTL was mounted on my camera for remote triggering and SB700 was mounted on the PocketWizard FlexTTL5.
- Flash was set for TTL.
- The flash was 4-ft away from the subject

When I increased the power of the flash beyond 1.3, the photo was totally black. I could see the subject pictured properly only when the flash was below 1.3.

I tried the same set up with my friend's D800E and ran into same issue.

Appreciate if someone could help me understand what is going on.

Thanks, NN

Comment: May i ask what the shutter speed is on this setup?

Comment: What exposure mode were you using? What were the following parameters for both the shots that turned out dark and the ones where the subject was properly exposed: shutter speed and aperture? What lens were you using? At what focal length?

Comment: I was trying with following configuration: Lens: `Nikkor 70-200 f/4`, focal length: `70mm`, f-stop: `4`, shutter speed: `1/250`, ISO: `800`, metering mode: `Spot`. Same configuration was used for both D90 and D800E. I turned on **Auto-FP** feature ON. Please let us know if any more details are needed.

Comment: My apologies for missing the info; I was using **Manual** mode.

Comment: I think the problem is the 1/250 at least on d90, since the max sync speed on it is 1/200 i think. I don't think Auto-FP works on remote flash using FlexTTL.

Comment: @YaoBoLu, Auto-FP is a way to enable HSS on cameras (at least this is what I understand); FlexTTL uses its own ControlTL mechanism to make HSS works, it does it in its own proprietary way. Plus, what I fail to understand is, if this whole Auto-FP does not work, how it is working for certain flash power (below 1.3 power it works). And, I tested with D800E to check if this is an issue with D90, but D800E also showed same symptom.

Comment: Just a question have you seen this information? [FlexTT5-Nikon - Compability](http://www.pocketwizard.com/products/transmitter_receiver/36/TT5-N/compatibility/) i just saw something about taking photos at the sync speed in the chapter about "ControlTL Transmit Priority at X-sync"

Comment: @YaoBoLu, Thank you for pointing me to the document; one interesting thing I found on that link is; let me try my settings as per this when I reach home from my work :)  **Speedlight Light Pattern** – The SB-910, SB-900, and SB-700 have a special Light Pattern Menu, which allows you to set a slightly different light output pattern. Of the three options in this menu, “STD” for Standard output must be selected. Selecting either “CW” for Center-Weighted or “EVEN” for Even output is not supported and may result in exposure errors.

Comment: Did you wait for the flash to recycle?  The higher you set the power on a flash, the longer it will take to recycle (i.e., be ready to fire again) between bursts.

Comment: @inkista, Yes, I waited for the flash to recycle (on both cameras).

Comment: Have you tried making a photo with slower shutter? If that works, then you just simply have syncing problem. If not, you have some other problem... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked my PocketWizard FlexTTL5 and MiniTTL manuals and literally I did not find anything. But when I checked these devices by connecting them to PocketWizard Utility software, there was one configuration which was not matching and to my suspect that was the culprit. For FlexTTL5, the HSS was configured to have 1/250th whereas MiniTTL had that 1/320th. This might have caused flash to sync improperly, thus, resulting in underexposed photos. I have attached an image for that configuration screen (in PocketWizard utility software).

Anyways, it was me who was the culprit to configure HSS wrongly (although I do not remember, no one else uses my camera equipments). My apologies if I have wasted anyone's valuable time.

[image]